# O365 delete events from Group Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

Trying to migrate from a Shared Calendar to a Group Calendar to get things more integrated into Teams, SharePoint, and Outlook.

I tried to copy events from a Shared Calendar to a Group Calendar by displaying the calendars in List View and using copy/paste. When I view the Group Calendar in my desktop Outlook, the events are shown. However, they do not show in the Group Calendar for anyone else (they are not synced to the server). I subsequently found articles explaining that events must be created as new items in the Group Calendar to be synced to the server, and some have suggested macros to do the dirty work (https://www.slipstick.com/office-365/import-appointments-group-calendar/). Ok, I might try this later.

My problem now is, I want to delete the events I copy/pasted to the Group Calendar that are only appearing for me in my Outlook desktop app. In my desktop Outlook I have selected them all and clicked "Delete", but they won't go away! How can I delete these events?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the same account that created the items? Do you have "Author" permissions on the "Deleted Items" box?

Comment: Yes, using same account and have author permissions.

Comment: @FrankLagattuta Hi, it's been a while, any update?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a way to fix this:

1. Shutdown Outlook desktop app.
2. Open Control Panel
3. Search for "mail" to the "Mail (Microdoft Outlook)" cmdlet appears
4. Run the "Mail (Microsoft Outlook)" cmdlet
5. Click "Email Accounts..." to open the Account Settings dialog
6. Double click my email account (only one listed) to open the Change Account dialog
7. Click the More Settings... button in the Change Account dialog to open the Microsoft Exchange dialog
8. Click the Advanced tab
9. In the Advanced tab, uncheck the "Use Cached Exchange Mode"
10. Click OK all the way back out of all the dialogs to save the changed settings.
11. Relaunch Outlook. All the Group folders no longer appeared. Send/Receive took a little longer, but I believe this forced a clean resync with the Exchange Server.
12. Close Outlook.
13. Repeat steps 2-10, but this time re-enable the "Use Cached Exchange Mode" option.
14. Relaunch Outlook. All Group folders re-appeared. The events that would not delete before were gone.

Basically, I believe these series of actions forced the Outlook desktop app Exchange cache to be invalidated, and this fixed the issue. Maybe there is a better/easier way to force the cache to be invalidated, but the steps above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to copy/paste(i.e drag) events from the shared mailbox to the group by the following action?

[image]

Based on my test, if I used this way to copy events and open the group member's calendar, the events will show in the member's calendar in OWA.